# Generic file uploading web service

Tags: java, web-services

I am developing a web service which is for file uploading. 
As this service takes only string in its argument which is the absolute path of file.
Then using java Stream classes i can write into my destination directory.
But how this web service will be accessible for clients.
How clients will use it.
Any suggestions here after what should i do.

I am mentioning this code here

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileUploadService 
{
    static String fileDestination = "/home/user/mywebservice/uploads/";
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    public void fileUpload(String fileSource)throws Exception
    {
        java.nio.file.Path p = Paths.get(fileSource);
        String s1=fileDestination+p.getFileName();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(fileSource));
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(s1));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(s1));
        while ((read = fin.read(bytes)) != -1) 
        {
            fout.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
        System.out.println("File uploaded to "+ s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on how you have structured your application. If this is for clients to upload files, then, as suggested below a UI would be necessary. Otherwise, if it is designed such that only other applications/systems use this for uploading files, then no UI is necessary.

Comment: I think i can put @FormParam("filename") annotation before argument of method.This can be tested via curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is supposed to be a web service. I guess you ought to provide a web interface for users to use your service (in which case you should probably consider using another language to create the logic, perhaps?). Otherwise you can create a Jar file of your complete program and provide the command line interface i.e. so people can run your program like:

`java -jar <jar_file_name> <path_of_src_file>`